# Minimum and maximum of $ \sin^2(\sin x) + \cos^2(\cos x) $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I want to find the maximum and minimum value of this expression:
$$ \sin^2(\sin x) + \cos^2(\cos x) $$

Comment: Do you know calculus? Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Found it among some questions of finding max and min of trigonometric expressions. Actually the solution is also stated along with the graphs of sin and cos, but i was unable to understand it.

Comment: @sdnr1, note that $(\sin \sin x)^2$ and $(\cos \cos x)^2$ have the same minimum and maximum, from which your solution follows.

Comment: Since $\cos$ is even it is enough to study $\sin^2 t+\cos^2\sqrt{1-t^2}$ for $t\in[-1,1]$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following George's hint,

Because $-1\le \sin x \le 1$, and $\sin x$ is strictly increasing on $-1\le x\le 1$, we see that $\sin (\sin x)$ (and hence $\sin^2(\sin x)$) is maximized when $\sin x=1$, e.g. at $x=\pi/2$.

On the other hand, $\cos x$ is maximized when $x=0$, so $\cos (\cos x)$ (and hence $\cos^2(\cos x)$ is maximized when $\cos x=0$, e.g. at $x=\pi/2$.

Hence the combined function is maximal at $\pi/2$, when it is $1+\sin^21\approx 1.7$.

For the other direction, $x=0$ gives $\sin^2(\sin x)=0$, clearly minimal.  Because $-1\le \cos x\le 1$, and $\cos x$ is increasing on $[-1,0)$ and decreasing on $(0,1]$, we minimize $\cos x$ for $x=\pm 1$.  Hence in particular $x=0$ minimizes $\cos(\cos x)$ and thus $\cos^2(\cos x)$.  Combining, the minimum value is $0+\cos^21\approx 0.29$

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me the answer in terms of sin or cos?

Comment: Minimum: $0+(\cos 1)^2$.  Maximum: $1+(\sin 1)^2$

Answer (score 3):

Your expression simplifies to

$$1+\cos(2\cos x)-\cos (2\sin x).$$

We optimize of $1+\cos u-\cos v$ under the constraint $u^2+v^2=4$.

$\cos$ is an even function, so we can say that we optimize $1+\cos 2u-\cos(2\sqrt{1-u^2})$, $u\in [0,1]$, which should be doable.

Comment: have you noticed the angles?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, my bad. I've edited my post.

Comment: How did you simplify the original the  original to $1+\cos⁡(2 \cos⁡ x)−\cos⁡(2\sin ⁡x)$?

Comment: @Ovi just apply formulas for $\cos$ of a double angle.